# Does Rails 4 support all new HTML5 <input> attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

Does Rails 4 support all [new HTML5 <input> attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_attributes.asp)? I noticed that HTML5 <input> attributes such as **min** & **max** and **step** are [supported in Rails 4](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#other-helpers-of-interest):

```
<%= number_field(:product, :price, in: 1.0..20.0, step: 0.5) %>
```

which produces the following output:

```
<input id="product_price" max="20.0" min="1.0" name="product[price]" 
step="0.5" type="number" />
```

But when it comes to new HTML5 <input> attributes such as **autofocus** and **required**:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" autofocus>
<input type="text" name="usrname" required>
```

then I haven't been able find any examples on how to apply those attributes in Rails 4. If anyone knows how to use **autofocus** and **required** attributes in Rails 4, then that info would be greatly appreciated as some of those new HTML5 <input> attributes would minimize the need for JavaScript in form validation in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<%= number_field(:product, :price, in: 1.0..20.0, step: 0.5, required: true, autofocus: true) %>
```

Pass `required` and `autofocus` as options to the input fields with value `true`. 
Above will generate HTML element as below:

```
<input autofocus="autofocus" id="product_price" max="20.0" min="1.0" name="product[price]" required="required" step="0.5" type="number">
```

Comment: It's worth noting that there's nothing html5 specific going on here:  rails' tag helpers like `number_field` will (usually) turn any additional options into attributes in this way, whether they are valid attributes or not.